# UINavigationViewController content showing phantom tabbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UINavigationViewController` and the pushed view controllers have the height of a subtracted from the bottom of the view (see image).

[image]

This is in a storyboard with the nav controller as the base. When I check the view inspector, the nav controller comes the top of the tab bar shown, but the next vc is a tab-bar height above. Anyone know how to get rid of that space?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Show storyboard or code

Comment: Add more details like storyboard and code, and also a screen recording of the behavior you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell the reason without more info and knowing your exact navigation hierarchy. However I'd start with checking `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property of your view controller and try to set it true (it helps in some cases with complex navigation stack).
If you want to do it with the interface builder you can find it in the Extend Edges section:

[image]

Also it's worth checking if the first 2 options are checked too (they should be by default).